# An error occurred in the Microsoft . NET Framework while trying to load assembly

Tags: .net, sql-server

After transferring the Database to another server, I am receiving below error while running a function which uses an assembly in MSSSQL:
An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65547. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'clrprocedure, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A)

After a long R&D, i got the solution. The TRUSTWORTHY property of the database was turned OFF previously.
ALTER DATABASE [dbase] SET trustworthy ON

But I have a new problem, my database is in read-only mode, and I can't apply this script. Tell me what to do?

The TRUSTWORTHY property of the database was turned OFF previously.
ALTER DATABASE [dbase] SET trustworthy ON